# Loading GIFs using SDWebImage is taking up far more memory than anticipated

Tags: swift, memory, memory-leaks, sdwebimage

I am building a UITableView populated with images and GIFs downloaded using SDWebImage. The images are shown in the table cells, whereas the GIF are shown as a 3D touch preview.

The problem is that every time a GIF is previewed the memory spikes (as expected) however the memory use increases far more than I thought it would. Downloading one of the GIFs manually, I found that it's only around 500kB, but when doing it in the app through SDWebImage, sethe memory increase is closer to 100MB.

After just a few GIF previews the app crashes due to memory issues...

At first I thought perhaps the instance of GIFView was not being deallocated when the GIF preview was exited - I checked with '''deinit''' and it does seem to be deallocating.

I also reset the GIFView to '''nil''' in viewDidDisappear but that did not help either.

Looking at the Allocations Instrument, I found that the GIFs are being permanently stored in memory when they are first loaded. This explains why viewing the same GIF again does not increase the memory.

Does anyone see why these GIFs are taking so much memory? I also built a version of the app where all the assets were local and that ran smoothly with no hiccups or memory issues - but surely the GIF sizes should be the same size in both cases?!

If there is no leak and these memory spikes are inevitable, is there any other way of clearing the GIF from memory when it disappears?

Code is below

```
//model
struct Visualisation: Codable {
    var id: Int
    let name, info, url_name, tags, imageURL, gifURL: String
}

//3D touch GIF preview
extension ViewController: UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

    func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

        guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
        let selectedVis = filteredVisualisations[indexPath.row]

        let identifier = "GIFViewController"
        guard let GIFVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? GIFViewController else { return nil}

        GIFVC.selection = selectedVis

        GIFVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 190)

        return GIFVC
    }

//GIFViewController

import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class GIFViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var GIFView: UIImageView!

    var selection = visualisations[0]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        GIFView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: selection.gifURL))

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool = true) {
    }

    deinit {
        print("DEALLOCATED GIFViewController class")
    }

}


//setting the table cells
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var TitleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var InfoLabel: UILabel!

    func setCell(visualisation: Visualisation){

        ImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: visualisation.imageURL))
        TitleLabel.text = visualisation.name
        InfoLabel.text = visualisation.info
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. I am sure you've already noticed that I am very new to iOS development... Pardon my 'newbieness'...

Comment: I've resolved the issue by clearing the image cache when the view disappears, but this may be bit of a blunt hammer solution...